# Migrate from Bentley PowerMap to QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, bentley

I have .dgn files working on Bentley PowerMap, these files contain LineString geometries representing city buildings distributed in several levels (Level 1 offices, level 2 parks...), and i want to migrate them to QGIS 3.0, converted to polygons.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you want to convert dgn files and edit them?

Answer (score 2):

**How to migrate .dgn linestring geometries to polygon geometries in QGIS:**

1. Use Bentley PowerMap to export .dgn files as shapefiles (.shp).
2. Add shapefiles into a QGIS project.
3. Run `Lines to Polygons` tool to convert the LineString geometries to
   polygon geometries.

If you are looking for a Python code solution, please be aware that gis.stackexchange is not a free coding service. Any request for coding help should include code that you've written so far, and a detailed explanation of where you're stuck.